# Can't set up port forwarding

Tags: web, server, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

So recently I started making a raspberry pi web server with apache and php, and so far I could change the html file in the default debian site and make my server go online, the only problem is that I don't how to make it public.I set up port forwarding but I'm not sure that which IP should my domain name point to (my local, or my public one) and also I'm not sure i set up port forwarding right, if possible please write down the port forwarding step by step (I'm using a D-Link router). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is your setup as following? RPi -> Switch -> Router -> ISP Gateway ?? If this is the case, you need to port forward inside the Gateway as well to get it outside ISP NAT. Even with that, it can be a dynamic IP. So you need a ddns service or https://github.com/nikhiljohn10/ddns-on-cloudflare (this is only if u use cloudflare). If possible, please update ur question with network diagram.

Answer (score 0):

For Port Forwarding open your router:

login >> manual setup >> Advanced Tab >> portforwarding rules >> give your local ip address of the webserver pointing to >> for hhtp(web) open port 80 >> save the settings.

there you go you can access your server from internet.

if you like, upgrade it to https using some ssl/ certificate process, there are so many youtube tutorials which could show this.