# How to set up port forwarding on router to access local web server?

Tags: flask, router, portforwarding

How do I set up port forwarding on my router so that I can access a local webserver outside the LAN network?

I have a local python flask application running at the following URL on a RaspberryPi, which is only accessible when on the same LAN at the following url:

```
192.168.1.11:5000
```

I'm trying to set up port forwarding on my NETGEAR Nighthawk M1 Mobile Hotspot Router by entering the following into the router form for Port Forwarding. My Public IP is 107.77.241.11 so I tried the following to no avail.

[image]

I also tried the following based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53520982/cant-set-up-port-forwarding), which also did not work

[image]

How can I access my python flask app with port forwarding?

Answer (score 1):

1. In my case i had to specify local details, not the public ip in case of urls
2. don't choose port 80, it might be blocked by another service, 5000 works ok
3. did you add host='0.0.0.0' in your Flask app?

Comment: yep - i used 0.0.0.0 in my Flask App. I'll try 0.0.0.0 and 5000